# Is this reinterpret_cast between RECT and POINT array safe?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, casting

Windows SDK contains a set of typedefs:

```
typedef long LONG;

typedef struct tagPOINT
{
    LONG  x;
    LONG  y;
} POINT;

typedef struct tagRECT
{
    LONG    left;
    LONG    top;
    LONG    right;
    LONG    bottom;
} RECT;
```

then, there's a WinAPI function that expects a pointer to an array of `POINT` structs and the length of that array:

```
void ThatFunction( POINT* points, int numberOfElements );
```

and we have the following code:

```
RECT rect = ...//obtained from somewhere
ThatFunction( reinterpret_cast<POINT*>( &rect ), 2 );
```

so that `RECT` is being treated as an array of two `POINT` structures.

Is such cast safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular Win32 structure, yes. You should of course make this assumption explicit:

```
static_assert(sizeof(struct tagRECT) == 2 * sizeof(POINT));
static_assert(offsetof(struct tagRECT, right) == sizeof(POINT));
```

Answer (score 9):

Because the Windows developers declared RECT and POINT right next to each in WinDef.h with the same packing, you can pretty much assume that it is safe.  The Win32 API, [MapWindowPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932750.aspx), is an example of a function that can be be passed a RECT or a pair of POINTs.  The docs even suggest using it as such.

Comment: +1 the packing is also defined explicitly, and it's this (non-portable) trick which makes the `reinterpret_cast` safe.

Answer (score 4):

I think that it will work the way you expect, but that's not what *safe* means, to me.

If you really want to play safe, the best thing to do is to create a whole new POINT object and set `x` and `y` accordingly with RECT's `left` and `top` fields.